# Method to resample 2d numpy array to a coarser grid and weighted by pixel area in python (analogy to grass r.resmap.stats -w)

Tags: python, raster, grass-gis, numpy, resampling

What is the optimal method in Python, when I need to resample 2d numpy array (grid) to coarser resolution (weighted by pixel area, the case when the new resolution **is not the exact multiple** of the original resolution) ?

In other words, for many years I enjoy GRASS GIS module `r.resamp.stats -w` when resampling raster data to a coarser resolution. Flag `-w` is important here, because the algorithm include the weight according to pixel area:

> With the -w switch, the aggregate uses the values from all input cells
> which intersect the output cell, weighted according to the proportion
> of the source cell which lies inside the output cell. This is slower,
> but produces a more accurate result.

E.g. resampling of **6m** DEM (left) to **20m** DEM (right) with weighted resampling is correct (image from [GRASS GIS manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.resamp.stats.html)). What would be the analogy of this GRASS module in *Python numpy* or *scipy*?

[image: resampling DEM from 6m to 20m grid]

Comment: Maybe some [filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.filters)?

Comment: Hmm, so far I was not able to replicate the behaviour with any of the scipy.ndimage or scipy.interpolate. Any further specific hint on scipy is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use OpenCV then you could use [`cv.resize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) with the [`cv.INTER_AREA`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121acf959dca2480cc694ca016b81b442ceb) flag

Comment: Thank you @mikewatt, this really helps. I was reluctant to bring another dependency to the code, _opencv_ is big. But even after thorough study of numpy and scipy I am not able to reproduce INTER_AREA there. Just for completness a short python3 example:

`import numpy as np  \n   import cv2 as cv   \n   a = np.arange(9.).reshape((3, 3))   \n
cv.resize(a,(2,2),0,0,interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)`